# How to make a font thinner?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

[image]

This font looks like a "thin" Open Sans, how they do it? Or maybe it's a different font?

Comment: Your question needs a little more detail. Are you asking how to create different versions of fonts? Or how to **select** a thinner version of the font? If it's the latter, your question will most likely be off topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are actually a handful of different weights for Open Sans. This is most likely the [Open Sans Light 300](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since it's already pointed out there is a thin weight for Open Sans called Open Sans Light 300 there is actually a way you can create thin text within Illustrator.

Convert the text to an outline by:

- Switch to the Selection tool and choose **Type → Create Outlines**.
- You can also use the keyboard command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (Mac).
- Select the text and **Right click → Create Outlines**.
- After the text has been converted to outlines add a stroke in the
  stroke panel or **Window → Stroke**:

[image]

- Select *Align Stroke To Inside*:

[image]

- Select the outside paths of the text and delete.
- I would suggest after removing the original type path for you to kern the type.

A good video to watch about kerning is "[Typography Tip To Help With Kerning](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jW_-2-7bzHQ)" but you could adjust the kerning before converting the text to outlines.

EDIT:
AS indicated by DA01's comment I would also like to address this method is not ideal for body text and it should be reviewed with a fine tooth if you plan on using this for Serif Fonts.  Especially look at the Ear, Terminal, Tail, and Bracket.

Answer (score 3):

It's a different weight. Fonts usually come with a variety of typefaces that vary in weight (thin, regular, black, etc.) and also include oblique/italic variants often times as well.

These different weights or styles aren't "applied" to a font as much as they are separate typefaces themselves. Meaning if you would like a typeface to carry a different weight you should have that typeface available to you at that weight.

While there are certainly means to "fake" the weight of a font (make it bolder, italicize it) it is usually not recommended as having the actual typeface at the weight is preferable because it was designed to be viewed at the weight that it is.

As [jos.lemmons pointed out, the Open Sans font](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) contains a variety of weights.

Answer (score 0):

Graphic trick:

Many vector graphic apps let you control the stroke (line weight) that is used to draw a font. You can often change this size of the stroke to make a font heavier or lighter. Affinity Designer does this and I think so does AI.

For some apps, you need to convert your type to outlines first.

Comment: Is there reference doc for how to do this in Affinity? I don't know of any way to modify a font's thickness in Illustrator without outlining first, it surprises me that Affinity can do that

Answer (score 0):

Adding a missing step in Darthvader's comment:

- applying strokes (inside)
- expanding appearance of the shape
- deleting the outside path of the text

The outside path cannot be deleted if we dont expand appearance.

Answer (score -1):

There is no solitary reaction for "any type of" typeface editing as well as enhancing the device, as positioned in the inquiry. All at once, any type of such procedure in virtually any type of tool will certainly make the most of more manual taking care of later.

In FontLab Workshop 5: Probably To Gadgets > Activities > Effects > Bold as well as additionally enter an adverse number. A lot more unfavorable the number, the more weight will absolutely be done away with.

In FontLab VI: Probably To Tools > Activities > Shape > Modification Weight as well as move the slider to a negative number ... Numerous various other gadgets will absolutely have other commands, or sometimes might be losing out on the ability absolutely.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer seems to have some major translation problems which make it almost incomprehensible.